# Why is curl not working through python but works fine in command prompt?

Tags: python, curl, subprocess

curl www.google.com works in command prompt but when I tried putting it in python it gives the following error :`'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I tried using both subprocess.call and os.system both give the same error

```
from subprocess import call
import os
os.system('curl www.google.com')
call('curl www.google.com',shell=True)
```

I am using windows 10 pro

Comment: What if you try `'/usr/bin/curl www.google.com'` (or whatever your path to `curl` is)?

Comment: What OS are you on ?

Comment: it is giving The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: If you are using windows You have to add curl path in sytem as well user environment variable

Comment: yes I've added the path to curl in both the environment variables. But why does it work in command prompt but not in python?

Comment: Instead of forking a process with `os.system` for `curl` command it is best to use [requests](https://realpython.com/python-requests) module. For example: `import requests; requests.get('www.google.com')`

Comment: this was just an example I have to send -u APIkey and a Private key which I am sending through curl

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own Question.

cURL comes pre-installed with Windows.
I was able to make it work by re-installing cURL to a new location and adding the paths in environment variable.